# Type Script - React Native : Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Date])

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, momentjs

I try to display the contents of **hours** but I get an error that is not clear to me because it just a date object.

What is the correct way to solve the following error :

״Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Date]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead״

```
hours = 2022-08-31T05:23:14.997Z

     <Text>{hours}</Text>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
    let hours = new Date('2022-08-31T05:23:14.997Z')
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
     <Text>{hours.getHours() + ':' + hours.getMinutes() + ':' + hours.getSeconds()}</Text>
   </View>
);
```

Comment: But you didn't refer to my object {hours} which already returns me new Date()
I would appreciate if you fix your code with my object